# Messed up footer in mobile view

Tags: html, css

The footer (fixed footer) of my [website](http://www.jobspacegh.com/) looks great in the desktop view but it is messed up in the mobile view. It is extremely large and covers part of the content.

In my research, the same question was asked by someone at WordPress support, but no answer has yet been given. hope your answer helps.

Comment: You need to provide code, examples of what you tried. Not just comments that something is not working. We cant help like this. Provide code and add it to https://jsfiddle.net/ as an example for us to investigate and help you.

Comment: well, another one of those "i have this problem but I don't post the code" question

Comment: well, this website isn't by any means mobile friendly... it doesn't even use any sort of responsive design... if you want to build a professional looking website with very little effort you should look into bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can solve footer problem for mobile view by changing `margin-top: 1070px` to `margin-top: 50px` & by adding `float: left` property to `#footer` selector.

**Updated CSS:**

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 850px;
    background: #6600cc;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shishir, the problem is fixed. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Give css style for footer :

```
    #footer 
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I suggest you use bootstrap for responsive sites.